# Permission Denied (Error 70) when executing procedure

Tags: vba, permission-denied

I did everthing needed but still I get an err = 70
on

```
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
when
Dim regex As Object
```

I enabled the "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5" in Tools -> References. prior to execution

```
Sub ReadcsvFilewithquote()
    Dim strLine As String
    Dim rowArray() As String
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim TSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set TSO = FSO.OpenTextFile("G:\dwn_c\mine\uhcdo\uhcgs21.csv")
    Do While Not TSO.AtEndOfStream
       strLine = TSO.ReadLine
       rowArray = Split(changeDelimiter(strLine), "#|#")

       ActiveCell = strLine
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
    TSO.Close
    Set TSO = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
Private Function changeDelimiter(line As String) As String
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.regexp")
    RegEx.IgnoreCase = True
    RegEx.Global = True
    RegEx.pattern = ",(?=([^" & Chr(34) & "]*" & Chr(34) & "[^" & Chr(34) & "]*" & Chr(34) & ")*(?![^" & Chr(34) & "]*" & Chr(34) & "))"
    changeDelimiter = RegEx.Replace(line, "#|#")
End Function
```

Comment: Possibly a problem with your antivirus software, if you have one installed.

Comment: Try `Set RegEx = New RegExp`. This use the Reference defined in Tools menu.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, which was resolved when I disabled my antivirus software (Malwarebytes).